# Is there any situation where I should not use --init when running a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, init, zombie-process

I've been reading about docker and the zombie process problem and find out that in the new(ish?) version is possible to use the flag `--init` to use tini do handle the problems generated by PID 1.

https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/

https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#init

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ (Section Specify an init process)

I get that build an image and put tini inside it may not always be possible, but now it is given for free (maybe there is a cost I'm not seeing) by the platform.